# When IPC using TCP loopback, can data be redirected to another PC to analyze?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, ip, ipc

It is not possible to analyze data sent as a loopback to localhost in windows.
But what if we edit hosts file, setting 127.0.0.0 to the another IP that host have (on different ethernet adapter), or to vmware virtual PC IP address, then we'll try to analyze data recieved with wireshark, will it work? 
What I am trying to achieve, is to recieve json-over-tcp data sended from one app to another. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: I think you should ask this on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) since this question is about networking related issues

Comment: Found this while googling http://ig2600.blogspot.ru/2011/03/powershell-script-to-enable-windows-to.html